# Android Facebook Logout

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook connect into my app using the Android Facebook SDK. Everything works great, I just have a question regarding logout. When a user logs out of the actual Facebook app, and returns to my app their session is still valid. **Shouldn't logging out of Facebook itself invalidate the Facebook session for my app?** Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear about your question, if you have a **logout problem from facebook account in your app** than Visit Following link, This May Help You :)

[facebook sdk in android app, only able to login, but not able to logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334545/by-using-facebook-sdk-in-android-app-only-able-to-login-but-not-able-logout)