# facebook sdk in android app, only able to login, but not able to logout?

Tags: android, facebook

**in facebook sdk 3.0 logout not working**

I have already tried

**1.**

```
Facebook mFb=new Facebook("xxxxxxxx");
mFb.logout(this);
```

**2.**

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) 
 {
  Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
 }
Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

Comment: I thought,this mFb=new Facebook("xxxxxxxx") deprecated.

Comment: you know any new tutorials available for facebook integration in android ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this may help you...**

```
public void logoutFromFB() 

mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {

@Override
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

Log.d("Logout from FB", response);


        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
            // User successfully Logged out
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
clearUserPrefs(); // user prefrs

session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

and invoke your facebook login activity

UPDATE:

You could use the traditional google account manager service to logout

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] accountsList = manager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE); //  ACCOUNT_TYPE =  com.facebook.auth.login

for(int i=0;i<accountsList.length;i++)
    manager.removeAccount(accountsList[i], null, null);
```

Comment: `ACCOUNT_TYPE`  is a constant with string `com.facebook.auth.login`

Comment: this is a string constant. `com.facebook.auth.login` is the account type you use to login to facebook.